Why doesn’t exFAT flash drive work on Windows 11, but does on Windows 10?
I had had a 64GB USB flash drive formatted as a live bootable USB, then was done and formatted it with exFAT from a Linux (Kubuntu Noble) computer using mkfs.exfat. I want to use it to share (large) files between various computers.
One is a Windows 10 device, and it was able to read/write to the drive no problem. But on my Lenovo Windows 11 laptop, I cannot see the drive in explorer. It shows up in Disk Management as Disk 0 Partition 1, and as completely empty and the filesystem entry is blank, and I cannot assign it a drive letter (option is greyed out). I tried uninstalling and reinstalling device drivers, I tried both of my otherwise fully functional USB ports, I tried hot-plugging and cold-plugging, I tried unchecking the power save option for the USB 3.0 Root Controller, I tried updating Windows and trying again; nothing has worked.
Is there a way to fix this (short of copying ~40GB of files and reformatting it from Windows 11)? It worked with Windows 10, why not 11?
Here is a screenshot of what Kubuntu recognizes the drive as:

Here is what Windows 11 sees:

Note that Windows 11 does make a sound acknowledging plugging the drive in.
I cannot right now get screenshots from Windows 10.

You are positive it’s actually exFAT because Windows 11 absolutely supports exFAT

yes I had to install an additional package from the Ubuntu repositories to use mkfs.exfat

Can you provide screenshots which show the file system used on the partition

@Ramhound I added one.

The right context menu is blocking 90% of the screenshot but what I see is a NTFS partition and partitions that are NOT exFAT.

That's pretty much the problem. Windows 11 won't acknowledge that it's exFAT even though that's what I formatted it to be and it is (at least to Kubuntu).

The only two partitions are EFI and WinRE, based on their size.

That one (disk 0) is the computer's hard drive. Disk 1 is the usb device. Their the same size (64GB) so I guess that wasn't clear
